# how to add custom function as option to validate, in the jquery validation plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I am using the jquery validation plugin: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options.

I would like to run a custom function to add css styling to the validated fields after validation depending on whether validation succeeds or fails in each field. I have tried highlight, unhighlight and showerrors, but am having trouble getting theses working the way I want.

I would like to add a custom function as an option to validate, or alternatively run a function right after validate each time it fires.

Here is a code sample:

```
$("#registerHere").validate({
                rules:{
                ............... 
                },
                messages:{
                .................   
                },
            validClass: 'success',
            errorClass: "error",
            errorElement: "span",  

                               unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
                    $(element).parents('.control-  group').addClass('success');  
                                    $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass(errorClass).addClass(validClass); 

                },
                        highlight:function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                        $(element).parents('.control-   group').addClass('error');
                         $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass(errorClass).removeClass(validClass); 
                    },
                                showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {

                                this.defaultShowErrors();
                                    $('.control-group').removeClass('error').addClass('success').

                            }

        });
    });
  </script>
```

I want to add the following code instead of showerrors, highlight or unhighlight:

```
if ( $('div.control-group').find('span.error').length) {$(this).addClass('error').removeClass('success');}
```

I would appreciate any advice,

Thank you,

Bill

Comment: What exactly have you tried that hasn't worked? Can you show some code?

Comment: Thanks for looking at it Andrew. I've added a good portion of the code I'm using. Highlight, Unhighlight and Showerrors seem to focus on adding error and sucess classes to input elements, whereas I am tring to add them to the parent .control-group ( using twitter bootstrap ). I've been playing around with it for days , but I think it may be better to remove all 3 and add in a single line of  my own code. - Bill